What is the right way to implement the new() method for the struct having a sysinfo::System field?
Given the struct below:
use sysinfo::{System, Pid, Process};
pub struct SystemInfo<'a> {
    sys: System,
    process: &'a Process,
}

How to implement the new() method? In this method, I want to return a SystemInfo object; the sys field should be a sysinfo::System object; the process field should be the process object corresponding to the running application. The process field depends on the sys field. I try the code below, but it has referencing temporary value error.
pub fn new() -> Self {
    let sys = & System::new_all();
    let process = sys.process(Pid::from(process::id() as usize)).expect("Failed to get process");
    SystemInfo {
        sys,
        process,
    }
}

How to implement the new() method?

This is a self-referential structure and not really expressible with Rust's lifetimes. You need to either change up your hierarchy or if you absolutely need value and reference self-contained, there are crates mentioned in the duplicate Q&A answers that can help.
